# How to have desired page reached when a user selects "Open in New Tab"/"Open in New Window" rather than clicks with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, url-parameters

I am grabbing parameters from the URL and passing them to other pages on the site, so I've used this code to do it...

For...

```
https://example.com/page1/?Id=12345&Email=email@email.com
```

I can pass the parameters "Id" and "Email" to the next page with the code below...

```
<script>
const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
const infusionId = params.get("Id");
const infusionEmail = params.get("Email");
const page2 =()=>window.location.assign(`https://example.com/page2/?Id=${infusionId}&Email=${infusionEmail}`);
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="page2()">Click here to get to Page 2</a>
```

This works fine when I click the link to get to next page, but if I right-click the link and select "Open in New Tab" "Open in New Window" "Open in Incognito"... the same page reloads...

How can I set this up to work for right clicking the link and selecting to view the destination page (Page 2 in this example) in the new tab or window or incognito... or whichever way browsers can allow the destination page to show up in the browser?

Comment: You would update the link's `href` when the page loads, and let the browser handle the tab opening instead of having an `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path to page2 in the `href` and copy all the params directly to the `search` property of the `<a>` element from `location.search`.

An `<a>` element has all the same properties as `location` does.

If you need to remove some of the params from current page before passing to the `<a>` you can loop through a `URLSearchParams()` object and remove them from the object and pass the object itself to

```
 linkElement.search = mySearchParamsObject
```

also without needing to parse to string

```js
// demo only add search params to url
history.pushState(null, null, '/?Id=12345&Email=email@email.com')

const link = document.querySelector('a')
link.search = location.search;

console.log('Updated href:\n', link.href)
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com/page2/" >Click here to get to Page 2</a>
```